# push tableViewController in a navigationController with if statement

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Here is an exctract of on of my If statement in the table view delegate of ProfilTableViewController.m :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
UITableViewCell *currentCell =(UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
if (currentCell.textLabel.text==@"phrase") {
    MainViewController *phraseViewController =[[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mesPhrase" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:phraseViewController animated:YES];
}
```

On the storyboard I created a push from a cell of ProfilTVC to MainViewController and changed the TableViewController to "MainViewController"

When I run the app, clicking on a cell from ProfilViewController doesn't do anything :/
wtf?

cheers,
Louis

Comment: why don't you use prepareForSegue?

Comment: From what I read (and understood) prepareforsegue is meant to pass info to the new view.

however, I use a segue from the a cell to the new tableviewcontroller. I set it with storyboard.


do I get it right?

Comment: I actually started over a tab bar based project and it works well.
Nothing was really helpfull with the last one, I guess I missed a big thing.thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentCell.textLabel.text==@"phrase"` compares the addresses of strings, not the content.  Look at the `isEqualToString:` method.

Comment: OK I changed the code, though it still doesn't push the view!

Comment: Inside the `if` try `NSLog(@"%@ pushing %@", self.navigationController, phraseViewController);` and see what it says.

Comment: it says : 
    2012-05-31 18:57:30.351 protov03[5300:fb03] (null) pushing <MainViewController: 0x6d88b30>

So it doesn't seem to push the new viewcontroller...

Comment: So the (null) is saying that whatever `self` is doesn't have a navigation controller set for it.

Comment: I can't figure out how to set the navigation controller though I watched many tutos etc. the nslog still displays "(null) push mainviewcontroller"

Answer (score 0):

now all you have to do is to use prepareFor segue like follow:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Make sure we're referring to the correct segue
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourIdentifier"]) {


   DestinationController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];

    // get the selected index
    NSInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
    //now you can add informations you want to send to the new controller
    //example:
    destination.selectedItem=[myArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];

 }

}
```

Don't forget to change the segue identifier: select the wire between the two controllers and set it in the attribute inspector on the right it has to be equal to youIdentifier